# Configure urn:jboss:domain in standalone.xml

Tags: jboss, migration, wildfly, pom.xml

I am migrating from Jboss to Wildfly.

I have this in standalone.xml

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.6">
```

But I have replaced old jBoss with this

```
<groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2.Final</version>
```

What should I set for `xmlns` in `server` tag? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. The wildfly-maven-plugin is for managing WildFly from Maven as is set in the POM. The namespace listed, as you stated, is for the `standalone.xml`. Are you seeing an error? You could likely boot with the 1.6 version and the server will rewrite the `standalone.xml` to the latest namespaces.

Comment: You haven't understood my question. I want to change xmlns accordingly to new wildfly. I need the new urn

Comment: Or it will be automatically rewrited as you are saying?

Comment: I'm saying it automatically will do that when you boot.