# Migration of standalone.xml from jboss to wildfly

Tags: maven, jboss, migration, wildfly, pom.xml

I am migrating from JBoss to Wildfly. In particular, from:

```
<groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>7.8.Final</version>
```

to

```
<groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2.Final</version>
```

I am using a standalone.xml file and other configuration files. Should I use the files as is? Or is needed some kind of migration?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77266385/152794

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure urn:jboss:domain in standalone.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77266385/configure-urnjbossdomain-in-standalone-xml)

Comment: Sorry, was a copy-paste error. Now it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `wildfly-maven-plugin` will work all versions of WildFly, JBoss AS 7 and JBoss EAP 6+. There should be no other migrations you need to make on the plugin. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin).

The version 3.0.2.Final is the latest that supports Java 8.

Comment: I must migrate the standalone.xml

Comment: This question was about the wildfly-maven-plugin vs the jboss-as-maven-plugin, not migrating the servers configuration.

Comment: read carefully: the question is about migrating standalone.xml

Comment: The snippets in the question are from a Maven POM and the wildfly-maven-plugin configuration. That has nothing to do with the `standalone.xml`.

Comment: Can you read a question or are you semi-blind?

Comment: I can and did which is why the answer is "Using the wildfly-maven-plugin will work all versions of WildFly, JBoss AS 7 and JBoss EAP 6+". The migration question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/q/77266385/152794.